# Создать пустую таблицу в Angular framework

Tags: table, angular4

Привет всем! я новенький в Angular. Стоит задача создать таблицу с N - количеством пустых рядов. Где N задается в .component.ts файле -  numOfRows:number = 5. Нужно чтобы в файле .component.html выводилась табличка с N пустими рядами(есть ячейки но они пустые, делается для того чтобы пользователь сам вносил туда значения).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать как то так:

Создай в ts файле метод(Который будет возвращать массив с размером **numRows**):

```
getRows(): Array<string>{
   return new Array(this.numOfRows);
}
```

Генерирование таблицы в темплейте будет выглядеть так:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Label1</th>
    <th>Label2</th>
    <th>Label3</th>
    <th>Label4</th>
    <th>Label5</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let i of getRows()">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```